# как получить последне значение поля у модели

Tags: yii2

есть модель, таблица (кому как нравится)  вот название полей

```
'id','name','id_operation'
```

`id`-автоинкремент
`id_operation`- может быть одинаковым у нескольких записей.
Мне надо получить последнее значение  `id_operation`, учитывая, что нумерация идет по возрастанию с нуля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение `id_operation` из последней записи:

```
$lastOperationID = Model::find()->select('id_operation')
                       ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
                       ->limit(1)
                       ->scalar();
```

Максимальное значение `id_operation`:

```
$maxOperationID = Model::find()->max('id_operation');
```